# CurrentRow in Datagridview changed before Validating by RowHeaderClick. Can i stop this?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have my current validation of the entered data in the DataGridView located in the RowValidating event. This is working fine for every scenario so far, besides the User clicking the Row Header.

In this case the CurrentRow will be set to nothing even before the RowValidating event triggers. Alot of my methods that are triggered in the case of the data validation are using the currentRow to access data from the DataGridView.

Is there a way to fix this issure without changing the usage of currentRow?

Comment: Please show the minimum code required to reproduce the issue and for what you've tried.